# Cannot start Rails Console - cannot load such file "ext/save-history.rb"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I recently upgraded my Rails 7.0.4 Application from Ruby 2.7.5 to 3.2.2

Everything is working correctly - I can run the server, tests, etc - but I cannot start a Rails console. When I do start a console I get this error:

```
/Users/my-user-name/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bootsnap-1.13.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require': cannot load such file -- /Users/my-user-name/src/ext/save-history.rb (LoadError)
```

I first thought that this is a Bootsnap error but when I comment out `require 'bootsnap/setup'` in my `config/boot.rb` I get a similar but different error:

```
/Users/my-user-name/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/dead_end-1.1.6/lib/dead_end/auto.rb:30:in `require': cannot load such file -- /Users/my-user-name/src/ext/save-history.rb (LoadError)
    from /Users/my-user-name/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/dead_end-1.1.6/lib/dead_end/auto.rb:30:in `require_relative'
    from /Users/my-user-name/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/irb/extend-command.rb:368:in `save_history='
    from /Users/my-user-name/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/irb/context.rb:137:in `initialize'
    from /Users/my-user-name/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/irb.rb:473:in `new'
    from /Users/my-user-name/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/irb.rb:473:in `initialize'
    from /Users/my-user-name/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/irb.rb:419:in `new'
    from /Users/my-user-name/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/irb.rb:419:in `start'
    from /Users/my-user-name/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:70:in `start'
    from /Users/my-user-name/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:19:in `start'
    from /Users/my-user-name/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:102:in `perform'
    from /Users/my-user-name/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /Users/my-user-name/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    from /Users/my-user-name/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/my-user-name/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/command/base.rb:87:in `perform'
    from /Users/my-user-name/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
    from /Users/my-user-name/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

This appears to somehow be an issue with the Irb session trying to load the library to save my Irb history? I've tried uninstalling ruby and re-installing, re-installing all gems with bundler, nothing seems to change.

I can't tell what the problem is though - is this a ruby issue, a bundler issue, an issue with one of the gems, and OSX issue?

I am using

1. RBenv 1.2.0
2. Ruby 3.2.2
3. Bundler 2.3.20
4. Rubygems 3.4.10
5. Rails 7.0.4

Worth noting that I deploy to Heroku and I can start a Heroku console without any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Dead_end -> syntax_suggest

Quite likely this will be a red herring but you can try migrating off of `dead_end` gem.

`dead_end` gem has been renamed to `syntax_suggest` and is a default gem in `ruby3.2`. [See the readme section for renaming](https://github.com/ruby/syntax_suggest/tree/main#syntaxsuggest). Try upgrading it to see if it helps.

#### Try adding `irb` to your `Gemfile`

[The mentioned file has been deleted in this pr, and on the version irb 1.7.2](https://github.com/ruby/irb/pull/613). Upgrading your irb might fix your issue.

```
gem 'irb', '~> 1.4'
```

`bundle install`

Apart from this can fix your issue, it will also benefit you since `irb` gets regular improvements while waiting to be included in the next ruby release.

#### If you are still seeing the same error

You might want to add these details to your question

- Are you using a config file like `~/.irbrc`
- Have you tried running `spring stop`
- Link your installed gems as a text file like a github gist

Comment: It turns out the `dead_end` gem (which was being included via `derailed`) was the root cause. It appears that including this gem in ruby >= 3.2 breaks things. https://github.com/zombocom/derailed_benchmarks/issues/233